# .submit() does not work when delivered via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I get some code via AJAX call I make by using Javascript. Everything works well with AJAX call, everything gets delivered when I check in Network tab(dev. tools).
Here is my code

```
        <form method='POST' action='some.php' id='next'>
        <input type='hidden' name='some' value='1' />
        </form>
        <script>
        document.getElementById('next').submit();
        </script>
```

This is the part that does not work. I check my html with inspect and all code is there correctly. When I put this code manually to webpage (without AJAX) it works well, but when it gets delivered via AJAX it does not, even if its get loaded normally (simply .submit() does not work in that case, nothing happens.)
Kind Regards!

Comment: How exactly are you getting the response and putting it on the page?

Comment: @Taplar xhttp.onreadystatechange like this, I put response to body tag. There are other parts that are being delivered too and they work just fine, I only have problem with this one.

Comment: Can you please update your question to show that logic?

Comment: Function for getting data?

Comment: The logic that makes the ajax request, gets the response, and adds it to the page.

Comment: Scripts don't run when you assign them to `.innerHTML`.

Comment: @Barmar That might be it